# Android: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) Error

Tags: java, android, io

I am following this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) to take a picture, save, scale and use it in android. However I am getting the `Android: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` error when trying to open/retrieve the saved image. After some research I found this post which assumes that this issue comes with files which contain digits in their names, like mine which are given a name with current time stamp. I checked that the images are saved in file directory and I logged to make sure the file name being used to retrieve them matches the original name.
Here is the part of my code that gives the error:

```
private void setPic(ImageView myImageView) {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = myImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = myImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
    Log.v("IMG Size", "IMG Size= "+String.valueOf(photoW)+" X "+String.valueOf(photoH));

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

And here is what logging shows me:

```
E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/JPEG_20150728_105000_1351557687.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And I am trying to open the image named: `JPEG_20150728_105000_1351557687.jpg`

Comment: It probably means that a directory in the full path you use does not exist: create it (using .mkdirs(), and _do not forget_ to check the return value)

Comment: @DerGol...lum it is a perfectly valid path (well, except on Windows filesystems). Of course one can wonder whether it was actually meant to use `file:/...` for a file URL, or whether the scheme is meant to be there altogether

Comment: @fge OK, I'll ask it better: Do you store your images **here**: `/file:/storage/sdcard0/...`, on Android?

Comment: yes, I do. And I checked that it is saved there

Comment: So, you aren't using a much more **standard path**, such as `/storage/sdcard0`?

Comment: Did you add reading/writing external storage permission on your mainfest?

Comment: @HarishSridharan yes I did add the following     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your code and tried to use the same in my application. Found that the prefix `/file:` causing the `FileNotFoundException`.

Replace your method will the following method.

```
    private void setPic(ImageView myImageView) {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = myImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = myImageView.getHeight();

    String path = mCurrentPhotoPath.replace("/file:","");

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
    Log.v("IMG Size", "IMG Size= " + String.valueOf(photoW) + " X " + String.valueOf(photoH));

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```